# How to solve login problems in liveserver using php

Tags: php

I am creating a admin panel. In login system everythings works fine nobody can not enter dashbord without log in. it works fine in local server. but when i live my project the session is not working. everyone can enter dashbord without login. so How Can  i solved this problem. I can also setup my database system and I can insert,read,delete,eyerything in live but login not working and I created this system using pdo.

Comment: Turn on error reporting (Google how to do that) and solve the possible errors.

Answer (score 0):

Include login check on the dashboard page

```
   <?php
            session_start();
            if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
                displayDashboard(); //This shows a lout link
            } else {

                loginform();
            }
    ?>
```